# How to specify action handler in router?

Tags: ember.js, ember-old-router

http://jsfiddle.net/pauldechov/u4naE/

```
App.Router = Em.Router.extend({
enableLogging: true,

root: Em.Route.extend({

    index: Em.Route.extend({
        route: '/',
        connectOutlets: function(router) {
            router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('application');
        }
    }),

    // why does this work?
    goHome: Em.Route.transitionTo('home'),

    // ...but not this? Am I missing something?
    goHome2: function(router, context) {
        router.transitionTo('home', context);
    },
    home: Em.Route.extend({
        route: 'home'
    })
})
});
```

I get an error saying:
"You must specify a target state for event 'goHome2' in order to link to it in the current state 'root.index'."

How do I define a handler here, so I can return false and stop propagation, for example? Should I actually be doing this in the view, and how would that be done?

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I can just give you an hint. When you remove the `href=true` in the template, this seems to work... but I have not yet understood what that means :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I've found it. When using href="true", you have to specify that your function goHome2 is an eventTransition. see http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/u4naE/2/

Comment: Thank you! By the way, is declaring all your eventTransitions a best practice even if you don't use `href="true"`? For functions only or for `Em.Route.transitionTo(...)` as well?

Comment: That's a good question. At work, we don't use it, so we don't define eventTransitions. Moreover I think it's a teadious work to keep eventTransitions hash in sync with the code (in our app, I think we have hundred transitions...). Perhaps by posting the question on ember js github, or searching for that will help you to decide what to do.

Comment: Looks like using Em.Route.transitionTo fill the eventTransitions hash: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/930

Comment: Perhaps it would be nice to have a function prototype syntax for this? `goHome2: function(router, context) { ... }.eventTransition('home')`

Comment: I've thought about that this night before sleeping. Perhaps it will be a good PR to make, or at least see what's ember folks are thinking about that.

Comment: What does using href=true buy you anyway?

Comment: it allows the `ctrl+click`, and so open the link in a new tab.